# Add a default parameter AddEventListener function call

Tags: javascript

I am creating a js function that takes all the id with some specific values and then add a event listener for all of them. All of them listen to the click event and when it's clicked it should call a function that has two arguments. These parameter values are unique for each id.

```
for (var i = 0; i < globalArray.length; i+=3){
  document.getElementById(globalArray[i]).addEventListener("click",
  loadTable(globalArray[i+1], globalArray[i+2]), false);
}
```

Here I have a globalArray that the first element is the id and the second and third ones are the first and second arguments respectively. How can I do that thing. Now each time it calls, not adding an EventListener.

But this does not call the function, only adds to event listeners then gets ready to trigger the 'some' function whenever the "demoButton" button is clicked.

```
document.getElementById("demoButton").addEventListener("click", some);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anonymous function which when called will call the `loadTable` function with respective arguments.

```
for (var i = 0; i < globalArray.length; i+=3){
  document.getElementById(globalArray[i]).addEventListener("click", function(){
   loadTable(globalArray[i+1], globalArray[i+2])
 }, false);
}
```